# Edge Marking not rendering

Tags: rendering, edges, freestyle

Posted this on another forum already, but at this point I'm trying to get as much help as possible. I've also already gone through a handful of other forums trying to fix freestyle edge rendering since it will not show up at all. I'm trying to recreate the edge effects in the photo on the right to get my model even more accurate. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in Freestyle's logic of inclusion and exclusion.

In any one Line Set, the relation between 'Select By' Methods is logical **AND**.

Here's an example cube with extrusions:

[image]

The inner cube's edges are marked Freestyle. The extrusions' outer faces are marked Freestyle.

If you 'Select By' Edge Type, (Inclusive, OR, Marked Edges) you get this:

[image]

If you 'Select By' Face Mark (Inclusive, One Face) you get this:

[image]

So far, so good.. but if you combine **both** 'Select By' criteria in the same Line Set, you get this:

[image]

.. because there are no edges that satisfy **both** criteria.

So the rule of thumb, to keep life simple, unless you need to make peculiar selections, is to restrict yourself to one 'Select By' method plus 'Visibility' per Line Set. If you need to select by two different methods, it will usually be a good idea to put them in different Line Sets:

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what actually fixed the problem, but after reading your answer I reset the freestyle settings and set it to or with only marked edges selected and that worked! All the lines and markings are showing up now. Thank you!

Comment: @LudicrousNostalgia   I did have a look at your file, and the selection method seemed conflicted: but I couldn't say 'Do X', because it wasn't obvious which edges you wanted. The 'and' relation between the line set select-by methods isn't well documented.